# How to "program" a bag that holds multiples types of things?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to turn a board game into a multiplayer game using java, but I have a few questions as to how I can achieve what I want.

In the game, there is a bag that holds Creatures, Buildings and Magic.  Each player draws from this bag to get their game pieces.  They then proceed to either put the pieces on tiles in the game board that they own right away, or they hold onto the pieces and play them at a later date.  The tiles can hold creatures, magic, buildings, forts.

Right now I have an ArrayList that is holding all of the creatures, and each tile has an ArrayList that can hold creatures.

It looks like an ArrayList is not what I want to be using, as I would have to have the ArrayList be of type Object (which is bad).  Any ideas on how I can design my program so I don't have to cast to Object?  I'm not sure if I need a wrapper class, or just multiple array lists, but The confusing things is when a player is drawing from the bag that contains a bunch of different things.  I should be able to differentiate what is moving around the board easily enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want to cast to object, create a superclass and extend all your characters to that class

Comment: Why is an `ArrayList` be of type `Object` bad?

Comment: "I would have to have the ArrayList be of type Object (which is bad)" - why is this bad? This is just Polymorphism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29), which is one of the most powerful things about object-oriented programming.

Comment: It sounds like you need a "Tile" interface / class.  If you're going to allow players to place them on the board, you'll need a shared superclass at that point anyway.

Comment: The problem with making an ArrayList of type Object is that you then have to cast anything you take out of it before being able to use it in a meaningful way. Use an interface or abstract class - if you don't know what these are, read about them, because they are a fundamental component of Java.

Comment: It seems like you have a common supertype here. Whatever you want to call it: GameObject, BagItem, whatever. There are many games that have this type of thing. For example trading card games like Magic and Pokemon have cards that have pretty distinct purposes but get thrown in a deck together. Also basically any game that has the kind of inventory where the player can put anything in it and move stuff around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an interface that each object implements:

```
interface Bagable {
    public String getType();
}
```

Then each object can be done in this fashion:

```
class Creature implements Bagable {
    public String getType() {
        return "Creature";
    }
    // Normal Creature Class methods...
}
class Building implements Bagable {
    public String getType() {
        return "Buidling";
    }
    // Normal Building Class methods...
}
class Magic implements Bagable {
    public String getType() {
        return "Magic";
    }
    // Normal Magic Class methods...
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<Bagable> bag = new ArrayList<Bagable>();

    bag.add(new Creature());
    bag.add(new Building());
    bag.add(new Magic());

    for (int i = 0; i < bag.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println(bag.get(i).getType());
    }
}
```

Or you could have the types as built in values

```
int ITEM_TYPE_MAGIC = 0;
int ITEM_TYPE_CREATURE = 1;
int ITEM_TYPE_BUILDING = 2;
```

and check them against these built in values

Comment: I think this might definitely be along the lines of what I need.  Thank you for your insight and help!

Answer (score 10):

Can Creatures, Buildings, and Magic all implement the same interface or extend the same class? Then you could have an ArrayList that contains that interface or class. Alternatively, just have a data structure that contains three ArrayLists and write code that picks fairly between them.

Comment: I would argue that the latter is actually a **bad** idea, since it makes the code way more complex, when polymorphism could solve the problem much more cleanly. There's nothing wrong with `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy The only "bad" thing about having an ArrayList of Objects is that it defeats the whole point of generics- what's stopping somebody from adding an illegal type to the bag? You also then have to use instanceof to figure out what was returned, which smells worse to me than the small complexity of 3 Lists. This is all subjective though, so OP should do whichever fits inside his head best.

Comment: Certainly a custom common superclass is the right answer. There are reasonable arguments to be made, though, that generics are not a neccessary language feature at all, and that polymorphism alone achieves most of what generics do (see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JamesGoslingOnGenerics). It is mostly a question of style, I suppose.

Comment: What would the difference of of extending versus having an interface be?  As I understand it, an interface forces you to implement certain functions, and extending is inheritance.  I don't know which would work better in my case.  Creatures are all playable characters that can battle each other.  Buildings provide income and Towers provide defense and income.  Creatures and Buildings are in the bag, Towers are bought with cash so they are held separately until put on a tile.  The only thing I can see that they would have in common would be the tile after they are placed on the board.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an interface, for example `BagItem` (which could define any common behaviours that the items in the bag would be expected to do), and have each of Creature, Building, Magic, etc, implement this interface. This would mean you could have an `ArrayList<BagItem>` (or other collection).

In my opinion, the real benefit to this is that common behaviour can be defined at the interface level, rather than just being able to stuff random stuff into the bag. If there isn't any common functionality between the items being put into a given bag/collection, then maybe consider having more than one bag (or maybe 'pockets' in the bag?) if that's an option.